# Referencing TypeScript Type Definitions

Tags: typescript, aurelia

I'm building an Aurelia app in TypeScript that utilizes [SystemJS](https://github.com/systemjs/systemjs)/[jspm](http://jspm.io/) and the [TypeScript definition manager](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/tsd). I have `.ts` source files under `/app/**` and `.d.ts` files under `/typings/**` and `/jspm_packages/**` (As some definition files are being shipped via jspm).

Obviously the TypeScript compiler doesn't understand SystemJS/jspm or TSD so I need to somehow reference the type definitions managed by them. I've tried passing all `.ts` files to the compiler so it references both the source and definitions but this leads to a rabbit hole of having to download all the type definitions imported by all the type definitions. It ends up being type definition [inception](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1375666/) (Yo dawg I heard you like type definitions). Seems that the compiler should only care about things *exported* by type definitions directly referenced by the source (and *not* things *imported* by those definitions).

Anyways, I get the feeling I'm going about this the wrong way and am wondering if there is a better/right way to reference definition files.

PS: Looks like there may be some solutions out there that involve editors/plugins but I'm looking for a strictly CLI approach as this is part of an automated build.

Comment: Have you tried moving your typings folder to inside the app folder? This way the tsconfig.json file that lives there will pick up your declarations automatically for you (and not the other packages from jspm)

Comment: It picks up the declarations just fine but the problem is it follows the references (imports) in all the type definitions. So for example, lets say I'm referencing lib A that references lib B. I should only have to include the type definition for lib A. But as it stands I need to include the type definitions for both lib A and B.

Comment: tsd should handle that for you... i.e. if I install the definitions for angular via tsd it automatically brings in jquery for me.

Comment: Ah, didn't realize tsd grabbed the entire graph, nice. AFAICT Aurelia's type definitions are not distributed on definitely typed so I guess I'd have to handle those deps manually.

Comment: You could add a file in your typings folder named `refs.d.ts` that could point at the specific `.d.ts` files within the packages that you've included which would be a manageable solution which doesn't involve moving files around

Answer (score 1):

I hate referencing files. What I do is I just use the "excludes" option in `tsconfig.json`. This guarantees that all typings files will be included in my entire project and I won't ever have to use any `<reference>`.

Just use [the following](https://github.com/urbanmassage/node-rabbitr/blob/master/tsconfig.json) tsconfig and you should be good to go:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5", // or es6
    "module": "system",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": true
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"
  ]
}
```

[Here's](https://github.com/urbanmassage/node-rabbitr/blob/master/index.ts) my main file in that module. Notice that there're no references to any declaration file.